# How to add transitions to semantic ui modal on appearance and disappearence?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, transition, semantic-ui

Semantic UI Modal comes with default `zoom-in` transition. How can I make it use some other transition on appearance or disappearance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UI transitions to change de default transition, use the following:

```
$('.ui.modal').modal({
   transition: 'transition_name',
   ... //others settings
}).modal('show');
```

List of transitions can be found here: [UI Transitions](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html), and also a list of modal settings here: [Modal Settings](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/settings).

BTW: you can specify one setting like this: `.modal('setting', 'transition', 'horizontal flip')`
so you get something like this:

```
$('.ui.modal')
   .modal('setting', 'transition', 'horizontal flip')
   .modal('show');
```